# Force.com Site - Data not loading - No log

Tags: visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, site.com, debug-logs

I have a simple Force.com site made of few VisualForce pages.

I use the same code also in Salesforce (button on Opportunity object). In Salesforce everything work very well but on Force.com site there is a bug.

Sometimes some of pages don't loading the data at all (data from an opportunity) and more than that ,when the data is not loaded in the page , this page do not appear in debug.

For example , in one of the pages , It suppose to display the opportunity products . Sometimes it's working and it is appear in the debug log,  sometimes no.

If somebody have an idea ?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect your issue is that Opportunity and it's related objects are not enabled/supported for display via Site.com licenses. You'll want to look more closely at the documentation about Sites to see what CRM objects are supported and which ones are not.

From [Sites and Site.com User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_sites.htm&type=5) in the documentation:

> Designed for **Performance**, **Unlimited**, and **Enterprise** Edition users who need access to Site.com but not to standard CRM functionality. Site.com Only users are entitled to the same rights as Lightning Platform - One App users, plus they have access to the Content app. However, they don't have access to the Accounts and Contacts objects. Users have access to an unlimited number of custom tabs but are limited to the use of one custom app, which is defined as up to 20 custom objects.

Comment: This is a Force.com Site, not Site.com. Site.com Only licenses are authenticated users; it seems like this will be under an an anon site guest user.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Look higher on the page I referenced. CRM Objects can't be displayed to guest users under a Force.com license, so the answer still applies. Unauthenticated users will have access to even less CRM object content under a Sites license than authenticated users.